# Can not copy files from PC to Galaxy SIII

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, samsung-kies, file-management

I have a Galaxy SIII GT-I9300 and 32-bit Windows 7 PC.

When I connect the SIII to the PC it gets detected and I can browse phone and memory card. But I am not able to copy files from PC to SIII neither using Windows Explorer nor Kies: The copy window starts and is stuck there only with little bit progress bar progress.

My PC can detect my other device (Samsung Galaxy Pop) and copy files fine.

I checked for updated drivers etc but everything is latest, USB debugging is turned on.

Any idea what I could try to solve this issue?

Comment: Is the file larger than 4gb? If yes it might fail because the Android FileSystem is Fat32 and doesn't support files larger than 4 gb. Did you open the USB Connection Settings? Slide down the notification bar and tap on more usb options. There you might have disabled file transfer. Else try to remove your USB Drivers and reinstall them. If this does not help I am out.

Comment: No, I am not able to copy file of any size but yes it seems issue is with my PC only, I checked it with other PC I can smoothly transfer files.